# How to load kendo grid data with ajax call

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

How to load kendo grid data with ajax call using dataSource.data method. I have tried following but it is not working. `$('#AAMaintenance').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.data(result);`

```
function filterOnSubmit() {
    var data = {};
    data["ExaminerNo"] = $("#txtExaminerNo").val();
    data["ExaminerName"] = $("#txtExaminerName").val();   
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("GetFilteredAAMaintenanceDetails", "AAMaintenance")',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ aaMaintenanceFilter: data }),
        success: function (result) {                              
            $('#AAMaintenance').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.data(result);                                                       
            $('#AAMaintenance').data('kendoGrid').refresh();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: _"it is not working.."_ This is not a helpful description of your problem. Firstly, is your Ajax call successfully receiving the specified parameter (`aaMaintenanceFilter`) and/or retrieving data from the server controller? Secondly, are there any console errors which may be helpful? Thirdly, can you post any other code you feel is useful for example, grid/dataSource initialization code? Lastly, it may also be helpful to see the structure of the data being returned (`result`) alongside the dataSource code, for example to ensure there are no spelling mistakes/incorrect data types specified etc

Comment: ajax call successfully returning the data from controller. The problem in this line ('#AAMaintenance').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.data(result);

Comment: So, simply put, the grid is not displaying the data returned from the server? Can you update your question with the grid/dataSource initialization code?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `dataSource` hasn't been setup for the Kendo grid control prior to the `ajax` call to retrieve the data, you should instantiate this before setting it as the datasource:

```
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: result
});

$("#AAMaintenance").data("kendoGrid").setDataSource(ds);
```

A few notes aside from this, and based on [Telerik documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource):

- If the `result` returned from the server is a complex object (unknown currently), you may need to look into [`schema.model`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-schema.model).
- Ensure that the `column` declaration `field` attributes match the names assigned to the object attributes you wish to display, for example note in [this example](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#fields-dataSource) how the `field: "name"` column matches the `name` attribute being added to the dataSource.